# How to make list searchable using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have dynamic number list , which could be more than 50 or 100.
I am trying to add search box, which would search numbers and highlight them, If number is scroll down(coz numbers are more than 100) , then it should be scroll down or highlight on top of the list.

I found this : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_list

In above link list is getting sort and showing filtered result.But I want all list but should highlight searched one using CSS.

Same like `chrome find`.

Thank you

Comment: Your linked example uses javascript, not CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reused the code of your example to add a class when an element match the search.

I simply replaced:

```
if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
  li[i].style.display = "";
} else {
  li[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

With:

```
if (filter != "" && txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
  li[i].classList.add("highlighted");
} else {
  li[i].classList.remove("highlighted");
}
```

Thus, when an element corresponds to the search, it is added the CSS class `.highlighted` which puts the `background-color` in yellow. If an element doesn't match the search or the search is empty, it removes the class:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (filter!="" && txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].classList.add("highlighted");
        } else {
            li[i].classList.remove("highlighted");
        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 6px 12px 6px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.highlighted{
  background-color:yellow
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```